# Stop console window from closing

Tags: c#, if-statement, time

I am trying to make a dialog in C# console... and I try to make it answer the users's question:

> "tell me the date and time"

or something like that. This is my code:

```
resp3 = Console.ReadLine();
if (resp3 == "tell me the curent date and time")
{
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now));
}
```

After it writes the answer to the console, it just closes.

Comment: Your code works for me.  What is the problem?

Comment: Consoles close when their execution is complete, you need a blocking call to stop it from disappearing such as `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Keep in mind: `tell me the curent date and time` and `Tell me the curent date and time` are **NOT** equal.

Comment: Please ask a question when using this site. I for one would greatly appreciate something like, "Why does my program close at the end?", or, "How do I keep a console application open after it's done executing everything?", rather than, "After it writes the answer to the console, it just closes.", which just sounds like random facts: "I like pineapples. Today is November 15th. I wrote a console app, it just closes at the end".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the basic structure, just add Console.ReadLine() at the end

```
   resp3 = Console.ReadLine();
   if (resp3 == "tell me the curent date and time")
   {
      Console.Write(string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now));
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
```

This makes sure that the program pause at the end whether or not the correct input was entered.

Comment: yea.. i think in the original code is a problem... i mean.. when i try this code in a diffrent project it works... if i use it in the original code it crashes... thank u ;)

Answer (score 3):

The code is finished, to continue you need to add this:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: yhea that is logic :D my problem was... "the consol is not showing me the date and it close after some seconds sorry for bad english..:

Answer (score 0):

You could make the code a bit cleaner and versatile:

```
var phrase = "...";
if(String.Compare(Console.ReadLine(), phrase, true) == 0)
     Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("0:HH:mm:ss tt");

Console.ReadLine();
```

The comparison will deviate case sensitivity, so it becomes case insensitive.  Also, you can do your format directly to the end of `DateTime` when you utilize the `ToString`.  It has all the same formatting as `String.Format`.  Also the `Console.ReadLine` is required at the end as Sajeetharan denoted.